# How to edit chart axes in python pptx - 'GraphicFrame' object has no attribute 'category_axis'

Tags: python, python-pptx

I have successfully built a chart with example data and am now trying to format the chart in python. I am attempting to manipulate the axes but have encountered this error:

AttributeError: 'GraphicFrame' object has no attribute 'category_axis'

I believe the problem lies in what the name of the chart is, but I have tried every possible 'name' for the chart that has been created.

```
chart_data = CategoryChartData()
chart_data.categories = ['18-24','25-34','35-44','45-54','55-64','65+']
chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (5,19,23,30,17,7))

x2 = Inches(0)
y2 = Inches(2)
cx2 = Inches(3.7)
cy2 = Inches(.75)

agechart = storyboard1.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x2, y2, cx2, cy2, chart_data)

category_axis = agechart.category_axis
category_axis.has_major_gridlines = False
category_axis.tick_lables.font.size = Pt(8)

value_axis = agechart.value_axis
value_axis.has_minor_gridlines = False
value_axis.Maximum_scale = 100.0
```

I expected major gridlines to disappear and the font size to drop to 8 for the category axis, while the value axis' gridlines should've also been dropped and the scale should've been changed. Of course, none of this happens because:

AttributeError: 'GraphicFrame' object has no attribute 'category_axis'

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's somewhat counter-intuitive, but the `.add_chart()` method does not return a chart; it returns the `GraphicFrame` *shape* that *contains* the chart. So to get the chart you need:

```
agechart = storyboard1.shapes.add_chart(...).chart
```

Noting the `.chart` at the end.

The shape itself is required if you need to change position or size, but pretty much everything else is in the chart *object* (a chart is not a shape).

The basic idea is that charts, tables, smart-art, and one or two other visual items are not PowerPoint shapes, but rather graphical objects shared by Microsoft Office file formats (think Excel charts being the same as PowerPoint charts, just in a different "host" document).

Because these are not shapes, they cannot reside directly on a slide; they need some kind of *container* shape to hold them, a shape that *can* appear on a slide. This is what a GraphicFrame shape is. It can hold a chart, table, smart-art, and possibly some other things.

Note that tables work in an analogous way. `SlideShapes.add_table()` also returns a GraphicFrame object, on which `.table` needs to be accessed to get the actual table object.

Comment: Thanks for your help scanny! Super helpful as always.